# Can't remove Schlage knob

Tags: doors, removal, doorknob

I live in a 60 year old house with several old Schlage door knobs as in this photo:

[image]

There is a small hole in the collar and two smaller holes on each knob. Pushing small sharp objects in the hole in the collar doesn't release anything. Ditto the holes on the knob.

I'd appreciate any guidance about how to remove the knobs so I can tighten the assembly or replace.

Comment: Is it keyed on the other side?

Comment: I believe the detent, when depressed, will allow knob cover to be pulled off the shaft. You may have to engage one side and keep pressure until able to release the other side.

Comment: Some knobs require you to insert the key, and rotate the cylinder 45 degrees before you can press in the release mechanism. As it doesn't appear that this is a keyed knob, the small holes might be there to give access to set screws (commonly hex screws, so you'll need a small hex key).

Comment: Other models have a collar that slides out of the way, which hides a set screw or release mechanism.

Comment: Turn the knob all the way and hold it there, insert a small stiff object into the collar hole to depress the knob retention tab while pulling outward on the knob. It will slide off into your hand.

Answer (score 3):

Turn the knob all the way and hold it there, insert a small stiff object into the collar hole to depress the knob retention tab while pulling outward on the knob. It will slide off into your hand.

Answer (score 0):

You must hold the knob and rotate that collar with a spanner.